# JQuery - Add class to every table alternate table row that doesnt contain a class name

Tags: jquery

I have a table like so:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
<tr class="special"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
<tr class="special"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
<tr class="special"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I'd like to do is use the zebra pattern on every alternate row that doesnt contain the class special. I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
$("table tr:not(.special):nth-child(even)").addClass("alt-row");
```

This still adds it to every even row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$("table tr").not('.special').filter(':even').addClass("alt-row");
```

Comment: This worked! I'm sure the others worked but this was the first I tried, thanks people! I'll accept this as answer when Im able too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('special') == false ){$(this).addClass('alt-row');}
}):
```

Comment: Not very efficient. jQuery methods (except those returning a scalar value) are executed on every elements in the matched set (returning a new matched set) so you generally don't have to use .each(). This is one of the top feature: chainability.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").toggleClass("special");
$(".special").addClass(".alt-row");
```